# What it Mike Zacharius grappling to?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 2 of the attack on titan anime, We see Mike hold off the remaining titans to give the others time to escape and warn other villages. But there is one thing that irks me, what is he grappling to?

[image]

Comment: I just rewatched this part of the episode. ODM gear can either be grappled unto: a Titan you are attacking or the surroundings (like trees, buildings and the like). In this case, it looks more like it's grappled somewhere on the Titan's upper part, either on the head, neck or shoulders. Or it could be attached to a tree at the back that is as tall as the Titan he's targeting.

Comment: But in the pic the hand is in the bottom, or i think its a hand

Comment: As I said, it could also be attached to a tree at the back that is as tall, or taller, as the Titan he's targeting.

Comment: After rewatching this episode the only thing tall enough to grapple to is the tower. There are trees but they aren't thick enough to grab on to, and all of the thin ones are short. Mike is 6'6 or 6'5 but either way, he is one of the tallest/biggest characters so it would need to be a big tree to support his weight.